# Can SQL/Access display foreign key rows as columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys

I have an MS Access table that has a many-to-one key to another one, and I would like a query to display those items in one row. For example, Foo, Bar and Baz link to the row with ID 1, so I would like to display:

```
1 | Foo | Bar | Baz
```

instead of

```
1 | Foo
1 | Bar
1 | Baz
```

Comment: Please post your SQL code. Change table/field names if you'd rather not disclose your real db structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Access's PIVOT TRANSFORM.
I think that is what you will need.